# Sending Mail Through PHP With MAMP Free

Tags: php, sendmail, mamp

So I downloaded the Free Edition of MAMP free, and found out that it doesn't initially allow sending mail through PHP.

My question is very simple. What is the best and easiest way to enable it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not really the answer you are looking for, but if you're set on sending emails try a program like https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

it will enable you to send emails through an SMTP server (like gmail). It will make sure your emails get delivered while working on localhost. When going live you could tell it to use PHP mail in the config (which is actually never recommended because of the spam factor and limited functionality).

That being said, while on localhost it shouldn't be necessary to send emails. Being that localhost usually implies a staging/development surrounding. What I like to do is output the to be sent email to my error log.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

You can instantly tell how it looks and you get confirmation that your script has run that part.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible for you to send email from local server like WAMP,XAMP.